# Opera "Search with"

Tags: opera

In Opera you can select some text and right click and select "Search with" to search the text with a search engine. Is it possible to configure it to open search results in a new tab?

Comment: It's always opened a new tab on this machine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can modify the entry in the menu text file. However, you might want to try just holding down the shift key. This actually works for all menu commands and will open it in a new windows, just like if you shift+clicked a link in a web page.

The following links may be useful for you:

- http://www.opera.com/support/usingopera/operaini/
- http://www.rarst.net/software/opera-context-menu-edit/
- http://operawiki.info/editinginifiles

Comment: Wow! I wonder why did not I test that before asking, shift works even  in  menus and textboxes , Opera is king of browsers!

Answer (score 1):

No, the search menu part `internal search with` can't be edited.
You can edit most of operas layout - but not that.

> The internal menus are generated by Opera and so cannot be edited.

Source: http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=1457182

However, you can replace the search menu with your own as explained in the source above.
But have in mind, that way, all newly created search engines aren't included in your modified search context menu.

Comment: Your answer seems to be off-topic. OP is asking to "modify" `Search with` menu to only change the way links are open, no to actually change items in this menu. However -- even assuming, that your answer is on-topic, it is incorrect, as you **can** edit items in this menu, by [changing default search engines](http://superuser.com/a/956101/156554). I can't verify your source, because link provided by you is no longer valid.