# Opera 31: Remove default Search Engines?

Tags: opera, search-engines

Up to and including Opera 30 you could follow [this link here](http://forums.opera.com/discussion/comment/15178242#Comment_15178242) which simply directs you to delete some `.json` file containing the default search engines.

Starting today, with the latest Opera update *31.something*, this trick does no longer work. If the `default_partner_content.json` file is missing (or things are deleted from it), Opera will complain on startup and ask for a reinstall. Putting the file back in place restores Opera to working, but the default search engines are there obviously...

### Has anyone found a new way to get rid of the default search engines?

(If I accidentally search that ridiculous yahoo again instead of youtube, as configured by me, I will lose my sh**.)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

> Go to **opera://about** to display your installation **paths**

- From **[root]/profile** :

Remove `default_partner_content.json` and copy  `siteprefs.json` to **[root]/[version]/resources**

- From **[root]** :

Remove `default_partner_content.json` then rename `siteprefs.json` to
 `default_partner_content.json` and set it read-only

---

As you may know, agreements with search engine providers are an
important source of income for the company.

[image: Opera & search engines]

Comment: And forgoing configurability is an important source of *driving away the user base* of the few % of super users they still have...

Comment: The default Amazon and Bing searches aren't secure (https) in v34.0 here so security would be a poor excuse.

Comment: In fact, looking at the `default_partner_content.json` file, even more are redirected through http ad partner URLs so, yeah. Nice job Opera.

Comment: On OS X 10.11.3 & Opera 35.0, *installation root* does not contain `default_partner_content.json`. How to adapt this process to OS X?

Comment: @Marcin the same issue ***installation root*** doesn't contain any `default_partner_content.json` or `profile` folder

Comment: @fgysin Attacking an income source of a gratis product from an ideological position shared by a small minority is futile. Privacy has become another currency, and virtually every human being blissfully pays with it day in day out. People have to re-learn that there is no such thing as a free lunch, and if they refuse to pay transparently with money, they pay in more obfuscated ways. If you'd like your privacy back, you'll have to educate Homo Ignorantis or achieve world domination.

Comment: This is not about privacy - it is about usability and configurability. I have seen big projects (even companies) fail because they drove away users by sacrificing usability to ad revenues... I'd hate to see Opera go down this road.

Comment: i'm not seeing these paths in Mint 19 xfce

Comment: Thank you so much! Confirms working for OSX 10.14.5 and Opera 62.0.3331.66. Finally!

Answer (score 1):

It's a well known issue. It's driven a lot of people away!

Here's a 'hack' which involves changing the launcher in itself. It works though!

(Source: http://forums.opera.com/discussion/1848915/opera-25-remove-yahoo-from-default-search-engines/p1)

1. Hit "WINDOWS KEY" + "E" (to) open the Windows Explorer - browse to
   your own files or where you want the script to reside
2. Right click in that directory --> "New" --> "New text file" and name
   it "OperaLauncher.BAT.txt"
3. Open that file in Notepad (or preferably Notepad++ if you got that)
   Paste the following code to it:

```
@echo off & setlocal  set "OperaProgRoot=C:\Program Files (x86)\Opera"
set "OperaLauncherExe=%OperaProgRoot%\launcher.exe"  set

"GetV=%Temp%\GetV.vbs"  echo Set
objWMIService=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")>"%GetV%"
echo Set colFiles=objWMIService.ExecQuery ("SELECT * FROM CIM_Datafile
WHERE Name='"^&Replace(WScript.Arguments(0),"\","\\")^&"'")>>"%GetV%" 
echo For Each objFile in colFiles: WScript.Echo objFile.version:
Next>>"%GetV%"  set Version=  for /f %%i in ('cscript //nologo
"%GetV%" "%OperaLauncherExe%"') do set "Version=%%i"  if defined
Version echo %OperaLauncherExe% - Version %Version%  del "%GetV%"  IF
NOT EXIST

"%OperaProgRoot%\%Version%\resources\default_partner_content.json"
GOTO LAUNCH_OPERA  : RENAME_DPC  ren
"%OperaProgRoot%\%Version%\resources\default_partner_content.json"
"default_partner_content.json.BAK"  : LAUNCH_OPERA 
"%OperaLauncherExe%"
```

I then took that .bat file and assigned the Opera 'O' icon to it, and removed the original shortcut.

Comment: Wasn't able to make this work... Also this seems to be just a script for the old Opera-v25 hack, which, as the OP clearly states, does not work anymore on Opera-v31+.

Comment: uninstalled opera for this.

Answer (score 1):

For Opera 36.0.2130.65 editing the `%operaversion%/resources/default_partner_content.json` *succeed* on Ubuntu and Windows.

Open the file in **vim** and remove lines, other than Google, from `"search_engines": {` constructs in that file, so it should look like the following:

```
{
  "version":8,
  "search_engines": {
    "location": {
      "at": {                  // a language code 
        "other": {
          "list": [
            "google_at",
            // yahoo and all others wiped there
          ],
          "speed_dial_index_list": [0]
        }
      },
      "au": {
        "other": {
          "list": [
            "google_au",
          ],
          "speed_dial_index_list": [0]
```

And so on in all language sections. Sorry I can not paste the whole file.

Edit this file, keep a copy and set the edited file to be read-only and/or set `opera://flags/#first-run-partner-content-update`  to *disabled*.

Comment: Hmm interesting, so do you reckon they disabled the file consistency checks? From Opera 31 on a single byte change in one of the files lead to an error and aborted startup...

Comment: I don't see Yahoo listed under the list for "us" and yet it's one of my default search engines. I don't care so much about removing it as I do about rescuing the "y" keyword, but searching for "yahoo" and changing keyword to "" doesn't work ... it just resets it to "y" upon startup, even with the flag you suggested set to disabled.