# How to remove default Search Engines?

Tags: search, opera

Below is the leading solution for Opera in the past but doesn't work for my version, Version:68.0.3618.165.

[root]/[version]/resources, path was not there so I created the folder path and dropped the file.  Went back renamed default_partner_content.json as suggested and restarted Opera and defaults are still there.  I'm not sure what's missing?

Any help would be lovely!

Why didn't I just add to the previous comment?  Because this site won't allow me to, so I'm expanding on the thought in hopes someone may have a current method of removing this.

Located at:
[Opera 31: Remove default Search Engines?](https://superuser.com/questions/956087/opera-31-remove-default-search-engines)

Go to opera://about to display your installation paths

From [root]/profile :
Remove default_partner_content.json and copy siteprefs.json to [root]/[version]/resources

From [root] :
Remove default_partner_content.json then rename siteprefs.json to default_partner_content.json and set it read-only

Answer (score -1):

For new versions of Opera GX you should replace custom_partner_content.json everywhere it can be found with default_partner_content.json and it's all done. And don't forget to close the browser before this action.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).